# Performance of WSARecvFrom with multiple threads

Tags: sockets, winsock, serversocket, winsock2

I am using a `WSARecvFrom` call to receive UDP packets in a UDP server. The observation is: when I am using multiple threads the performace of `WSARecvFrom` is degrading. What are the factors w.r.t threading that impact the performance of the socket and `WSARecvFrom`? What are the best practices to implement a UDP server using `WSASocket` for a heavy throughput case (~4000 packets per second).

**Update**

```
Constructor(...)
{
    io = CreateThreadpoolIo(SocketHandle, IOCompletion, ...);
    for(i -> 0 to number_of_parallel_receives)
        ReceivePacket(...);
}

static void CALLBACK IOCompletion(...)
{
    ProcessPacket(...);
    IncrementCounter();
    ReceivePacket(...); // get next packet
}

void ReceivePacket(...)
{
    StartThreadpoolIo(io);
    WSARecvFrom(...); // callback routine is nullptr and handled with the ThreadPoolIO callback
}
```

Comment: How are you measuring the performance? What does your code look like?

Comment: Updated. Observation is when I even turn off the processing in `IOCompletion` I still get less number in the counter with more `WSAReceiveFrom` enqueues in parallel.

Comment: There really isn't enough information, or code, here to answer this, but... Try using IOCP rather than alertable I/O? The later requires a thread in an 'alertable wait state' to deliver the callback...